# Eschewmenical Blog Christmas Tradition

Tags: discussion, blog

It might be appropriate to ask the [year's most productive Christian](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1039/affable-geek) to give the Christmas blessing on the [Blog](http://christianity.blogoverflow.com/), if he or she (and in this case he) is up to it.

What do you fellows think?

Comment: Whether Affabale want's to do it or not, we could use someone to give the Christmas blessing. Please apply below!

Comment: There's still time for a come-from-behind victory for [someone else](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=year).  ;-)

Comment: @JonEricson: Not without hitting the rep cap every single day between now and the end of the year plus collecting 5k in bounties! And that's assuming Affable is taking a Christmas break.